# How to convert string in a datetime.datetime format into a datetime object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime

I have a raw log which print timestamp in format of `datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 15, 0, 250362)`.
I believe some conversion has failed in the underlying program (out of my control).

Since it's a string, I can't do it with `strftime()`.

Any way I could translate this into a `datetime`?

Comment: "Since it's a string, i cant do it with strftime()"... Sitting next to `strftime` is its opposite function [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`datetime.strptime()` can be used to validate a string and parse a date/time:

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = 'datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 15, 0, 250362)'
dt = datetime.strptime(s,'datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, %f)')
print(dt)
```

Output:

```
2021-09-10 10:15:00.250362
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
>>> s = 'datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 15, 0, 250362)'
>>> datetime.datetime(*map(int, s[s.find('(') + 1: -1].split(', ')))
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 10, 10, 15, 0, 250362)
>>>
```